# How to NSKeyedUnarchive subclasses of NSManagedObject to import into Core Data?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, import, nsmanagedobject

An existing document based application that saves and loads it's data using `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver` is currently transformed to use Core Data as it's storage backend.

Now I am trying to have a kind of import of files saved using the former application. The object structure didn't change, but I changed all objects to be `NSManagedObject`s. Now the `initWithCoder:` calls `[super initWithCoder:]` and doesn't create the object using `NSEntityDescription`. That failes epically (as expected).

My question is: what is the best practice / a good advice to have such an import functionality?

Comment: After fiddeling together my own solution (with some banging-head-on-desk involved) I found the same solution described by The Mental Faculty:

Comment: You should move your comment to an answer and accept it so others can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way would be to implement a subclass of `NSAtomicStore` that unarchives the old data format into a Core Data representation. After loading the old data using that store, you can easily migrate the data using `-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:NSSQLiteStoreType  error:]`

**OLD (WRONG) ANSWER:**

After fiddeling together my own solution (with some banging-head-on-desk involved) I found the same solution described by The Mental Faculty:

[KEYED-ARCHIVING TO CORE DATA MIGRATION](http://www.mentalfaculty.com/mentalfaculty/Blog/Entries/2010/4/17_Keyed-Archiving_to_Core_Data_Migration.html)

I did it the same way they do, but I created my own subclass of `NSKeyedValueDecoder` that stores the context. The `initWithCoder:` of my `CBManagedObject` superclass to all entities looks like this:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)inCoder {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((CBNSKeyedUnarchiverCoreData*)inCoder).context;
    self = [super initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:[[self class] entityName] 
                                             inManagedObjectContext:context] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    if (!self) return nil;
    return self;
}
```

Each entity gives his entity name with the class method `+entityName`.

Seems like a good solution as it works very good by now.